# How to draw line, circle on scaled canvas with bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, scaling, zooming

I have an canvas with a bitmap image set on it. I am able to scale entire canvas with pinch zoom in and out gesture. Now I want to draw line or freehand drawing on scaled canvas i.e zoomed in. While doing so I am getting accurate result when canvas is not scaled but when canvas is zoomed in I am getting line drawn at some random position.

**Line drawing when canvas is not scaled**:

[image: Line drawing when canvas is not scaled]

**Line Drawing when canvas is zoomed in onTouchMove**:

[image: Line Drawing when canvas is zoomed in onTouchMove]

Result when user zooms out or onTouchEnd while drawing line. **Line should be at U as shown in the second figure.**

[image: Result when user zooms out or onTouchEnd while drawing line. LINE SHOULD BE AT U AS SHOWN IN THE SECOND FIGURE]

This is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    if(WriteApp.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("draw"))
    {
        isDrawing=true;
        int touchCount = event.getPointerCount();
        //Log.i("", "from on draw x"+x+" y "+y);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i("", "touch start x"+x+" y "+y);
            touch_start(x, y);
            this.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            touch_move(x, y);
            this.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i("", "touch end x"+x+" y "+y);
            touch_up();
            this.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    isDrawing=false;
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        mode = DRAG;

        //We assign the current X and Y coordinate of the finger to startX and startY minus the previously translated
        //amount for each coordinates This works even when we are translating the first time because the initial
        //values for these two variables is zero.
        startX = event.getX()-previousTranslateX;
        startY = event.getY()-previousTranslateY;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        translateX = event.getX()-startX;
        translateY = event.getY()-startY;

        //We cannot use startX and startY directly because we have adjusted their values using the previous translation values.
        //This is why we need to add those values to startX and startY so that we can get the actual coordinates of the finger.
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.getX()-(startX + previousTranslateX), 2) +
                Math.pow(event.getY()-(startY + previousTranslateY), 2)
                );

        if(distance > 0)
        {
            dragged = true;
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        mode = ZOOM;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mode = NONE;
        dragged = false;

        //All fingers went up, so let’s save the value of translateX and translateY into previousTranslateX and
        //previousTranslate
        previousTranslateX = translateX;
        previousTranslateY = translateY;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        mode = DRAG;

        //This is not strictly necessary; we save the value of translateX and translateY into previousTranslateX
        //and previousTranslateY when the second finger goes up
        previousTranslateX = translateX;
        previousTranslateY = translateY;
        break;
    }

    detector.onTouchEvent(event);

    //We redraw the canvas only in the following cases:
    //
    // o The mode is ZOOM
    // OR
    // o The mode is DRAG and the scale factor is not equal to 1 (meaning we have zoomed) and dragged is
    // set to true (meaning the finger has actually moved)
    if ((mode == DRAG && scaleFactor != 1f && dragged) || mode == ZOOM)
    {
        invalidate();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.save();

    //If translateX times -1 is lesser than zero, let’s set it to zero. This takes care of the left bound
    //if(((translateX*-1)(scaleFactor-1)*displayWidth)<0)
    //If translateX times -1 is lesser than zero, let's set it to zero. This takes care of the left bound
    if((translateX * -1) < 0) {
        translateX = 0;
    }

    //This is where we take care of the right bound. We compare translateX times -1 to (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth.
    //If translateX is greater than that value, then we know that we've gone over the bound. So we set the value of 
    //translateX to (1 - scaleFactor) times the display width. Notice that the terms are interchanged; it's the same
    //as doing -1 * (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth
    else if((translateX * -1) > (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth) {
        translateX = (1 - scaleFactor) * displayWidth;
    }

    if(translateY * -1 < 0) {
        translateY = 0;
    }

    //We do the exact same thing for the bottom bound, except in this case we use the height of the display
    else if((translateY * -1) > (scaleFactor - 1) * displayHeight) {
        translateY = (1 - scaleFactor) * displayHeight;
    }


    //We need to divide by the scale factor here, otherwise we end up with excessive panning based on our zoom level
    //because the translation amount also gets scaled according to how much we’ve zoomed into the canvas.
    canvas.translate(translateX, translateY);

    //We’re going to scale the X and Y coordinates by the same amount
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //The rest of your canvas-drawing code 


    canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    if(scaleFactor!=1.f)
        canvas.restore();

    if(isDrawing)
        canvas.drawPath( mPath,  dPaint);

    if(scaleFactor==1.f)
        canvas.restore();

}
```

Comment: you sre doing something wrong

Comment: yes,Thats what i am searching for.Have posted my code.please check and let me know where am i going wrong. :)

Comment: 1) get the Canvas' Matrix, 2) invert() it 3) using inverted Matrix mapPoints() map every touch point in onTouchEvent

Comment: hey thanks for the prompt reply but can you please show me the way to do it in my code.i am bit confused about the flow.

Comment: change your code by replacing canvas.translate and canvas.scale with canvas.concat(matrix), that Matrix will be used for inverse mapping the points in onTouchEvent

Comment: oh ok will notify you in some time after trying ...thanks again :)

Comment: Added the following code replacing canvas.scale and canvas.translate

Comment: Matrix matrix = new Matrix();matrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getClipBounds().right,canvas.getClipBounds().bottom),new RectF(strokeWidth/2, strokeWidth/2, canvas.getClipBounds().right - strokeWidth/2,canvas.getClipBounds().bottom - strokeWidth/2),Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL); canvas.concat(matrix);
added this and now canvas is not scaling

Comment: Called Canvas.concat ?

Comment: yes it is there .check the fourth line in my previous comment.Also am i doing it in a wrong way? please help i am stucked. :(

Comment: had just changed the image sequence in the question as per the result i am getting.

Comment: Getting a 3X3 matrix --> Matrix{[0.99583334, 0.0, 1.0][0.0, 0.9973753, 1.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}. What actually i should get according to you?

Comment: Btw, the better approach is to drawBitmap with Matrix param and not to translate/scale/concat the canvas at all

Comment: oh yes agreed on that point but my requirement is to zoom entire view including the objects drown above it and not only the background bitmap.And allow user to draw in any mode i.e. zoomed in or zoomed out.

Comment: So you have to modify the matrix in onTouchEvent only, in obDraw call canvas.save, concat, drawBitmap, drawPath and restore

Comment: I got your point but please can you help me with some code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Post your code first

For on touch pinch zoom zoom-out

Find this URL for reference

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java